# rendering network SVG images causes performance issues on android React-Native(I want to avoid use of React-Native-svg-uri)

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg

I am want to render network images in React-Native i previously used ttf method and that works great but this method is used only for static images i want to render svg images with light weight method, I know some of the libraries are available but they are very slow on android so i want to avoid these ones is any way to render svg images on android smoothly?

Didn't answered perfectly.

import Svg from 'reacr-native-svg-uri'

this library i am using currently.

I don't want to use this library because this causing performance issues on android.

Answer (score 0):

Agree. SVG image has a big performance issue. **If possible try to use RN image tag.** Otherwise, try these solutions:

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/issues/1232 or

https://medium.com/@wcandillon/5-things-to-know-about-images-react-native-69be41d2a9ee or

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fast-image

Comment: Image tags can be used with `png's` and `jpeg's` etc, I convert these images into `.ttf` file and use as fonts and this works great but this method can only work with static SVG, not with dynamic SVG files.